# i5500 update from 2.2 to 2.2.2?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, updates, samsung-galaxy-5

I have got a Samsung Galaxy GT-I5500. Actually there is Froyo 2.2 running on it. I read that with 2.2.2 there got a bunch of bugfixes released. Even though i know Froyo is quite old I never ever read about someone who upraded to Version 2.2.2 though. Everybody seems to stay with 2.2 (or switches to 2.3,...)

That's why I would like to ask if there is a way to switch to 2.2.2 even though my carrier doesn't provide it through kies???

--> I already found this page
[Official ROMs for i5500](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1087402)
but I don't really know about the JPJ/JQ3...-Codes. Even though it says that these ROMs should be 2.2.2 I am not really sure about that, because the Codes listed differ quite a lot.

My actual SW-Version: PDA XWJQ3 / PHONE NEJPS / CSC REJP2

Comment: The codes JPJ/JQ3 are related to the base-band version used, which varies from region to region. XDA does not host official ROM's, in fact, go to [samfirmware](http://samfirmware.com) that is the nearest to being official, all XDA does is mirror them from samfirmware.

Answer (score 0):

you can go UN-OFFICIAL , CM7 works great on it... a GB AOSP rom
more info [HERE](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1149110)

Comment: CM7 is broken on that, causes sleep of death! :) Try [madteam](http://madteam.co) as that is where psyke83 does a lot of work on the Samsung Europa.